# Do I need to check my intel graphics driver version and update it regularly?

Tags: drivers, 20.04, intel-graphics

I am also attaching a link to some open drivers I found while searching, do I need to install and update those or I am better off using what I have
Ubuntu 20.04LTS, i5 7200U, intel hd 620
graphics-Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)

[Link found on the internet](https://launchpad.net/%7Eoibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers)

Comment: i have the same graphics as you and it works so why fix it.it is allways good to keep your system updated but updating the grapics drivers separately is not needed unless you have a problem.

Comment: yes i probably dont need to update it, I was just curious.I face lag while scrolling on chrome and firefox , tried smooth scrolling nothing changed.

Answer (score 3):

**You linked to a PPA.**

This is not software that is officially in Ubuntu's [repositories](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu).  It hasn't undergone the same standards of testing and process review as packages that are officially supported by Ubuntu.

This could mean that the software might not work with your system and could break things.  It's also possible that the software has an unknown vulnerability which makes it unsafe or dangerous to install or use.

From the package description, it's not even immediately apparent which devices this package is supposed to support.

**Updates for your currently installed software, including the graphics driver you are currently using, will be updated when you update your system normally through the software center or `apt` / `apt-get`.**

*See Also:* [Are PPAs safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-for)

---

From the comment you made on the original question:

> *yes i probably dont need to update it, I was just curious.I face lag while scrolling on chrome and firefox , tried smooth scrolling nothing changed.*

It seems by asking this question that you might be caught in the trap of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): The actual issue you seem to be trying to solve has to do with scrolling in your web browser.  But it's hard to guess the reason for this or to suggest a solution because you didn't ask or tell about the actual issue you're facing (hence the XY problem).  Perhaps there is an `about:config` entry in Firefox that can be adjusted?  Depending on which DE you use, in system settings, there may or may not be additional configuration settings for mouse/scrolling.

Comment: Well browsers are where i face lag many times , but that scroll lag exists while scrolling through the gnome 'all apps' or scrolling in the software center , pretty much anywhere except text files , editors etc, chrome and firefox are where i face it the most